# Password checker. Problems with methods regarding the checking of the password

Tags: java

This is an attempted password checker. I wanted to check if the password is at least 8 characters long. If at least 1 character is upper and lower case. I also wanted to check if at least one character is non-alphanumeric. I give up for today. I am posting it stackoverflow because I was wondering if there are any people who could help me with this. I don't know yet how to be overly specific with the technical details of java of why my program works and I suspect if I did I wouldn't be posting it on stackoverflow.com. I'm of the same opinion of linus torvalds that java is a horrible language. I am forced however to complete 1 java class at my college, so I've been practicing. I am still new to this language. Below is my program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordChecker {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Password = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a password to be checked");
    Password = input.next();
    PassChkr(Password);
  }

  private static boolean PassChkr(String a) {
    boolean safe = false;
    boolean unsafe = true;

    boolean hasLowercase = !a.equals(a.toUpperCase());
    boolean hasUppercase = !a.equals(a.toLowerCase());

    // Does work
    if (a.length() >= 8) {
        safe = true;
        System.out.println("Your password is at least 8 characters long");
        // Doesn't work..    
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
      if (hasLowercase == false) {
        safe = true;
        System.out.println("Your password has a least 1 lowercase character");
      }

      if (hasUppercase == false) {
        safe = true;
        System.out.println("Your password has at least 1 uppercase character");
      }
   }

   // for (int i = 0; i < a.charAt(0); i++) {
   //   if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(i) == false) 
   //     safe = true;
   //   System.out.println("Your password has at least 1 non letter or digit");
   //   
   return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: First rule of programming, whatever the language is: read the error message. If you want us to solve a problem, you could at least tell us what the problem is. Java doesn't prevent you from doing that, does it?

Comment: I'm having problems with the non-alphanumeric checker which is commented out in this and also the line that checks whether or not it has 1 lowercase and uppercase letter. I thought it would be obvious. I'm sorry.

Comment: *I'm having problems*: which problems?

Comment: the non-alphanumeric checker which is commented out in this and also the line that checks whether or not it has 1 lowercase and uppercase letter

Comment: Some remarks: 1/ `safe`, `unsafe` are redundant (it's either safe or unsafe) 2/ the for-loop for lower/uppercase is useless 3/ you should return `safe`, `unsafe`, not `false` 4/ your commented test check `i` not the i-th char of a. Also, consider using properly named vars (not `a`) and method name should start with a lowercase letter (usual convention).

Answer (score 3):

I would break the problem up into the three tests (`containsUpper`, `containsLower`, and `containsNonAlpha`) I wanted to perform as follows

```
/**
 * Return true if the input string contains an upper case
 * letter.
 * 
 * @param a
 *          The input string.
 * @return True if a contains an upper case letter.
 */
private static boolean containsUpper(String a) {
  if (a == null) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(a.charAt(i))) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * Return true if the input string contains a lower case
 * letter.
 * 
 * @param a
 *          The input string.
 * @return True if a contains a lower case letter.
 */
private static boolean containsLower(String a) {
  if (a == null) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i))) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * Return true if the input string contains a non-alphanumeric 
 * letter.
 * 
 * @param a
 *          The input string.
 * @return True if a contains a lower case letter.
 */
private static boolean containsNonAlpha(String a) {
  if (a == null) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    char c = a.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isDigit(c) && !Character.isLetter(c)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for splitting up the tests; that makes the most didactic sense

Comment: Isn't this redundant b/c of the method in the Character class that checks both? if (!Character.isDigit(c) && !Character.isLetter(c)) {
      return true; I didn't notice this but, you actually get graded on a help forum lol? There's a method that checks both of those.. I like the splitting up of the problem but, the above and are the comments really necessary? I mean if someone can read java and figure out what it means, is it really necessary to elongate the program?

Comment: You certainly could use `Character.isLetterOrDigit()` my solution wasn't intended to be optimal (or I'd have done one pass, not three).

Answer (score -1):

i would do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
  if (Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i))) {
    boolean lSafe = true;
  }

  if (Character.isUpperCase(a.charAt(i))) {
    boolean uSafe = true;
  }
}
if(lSafe){
   System.out.println("Your password has a least 1 lowercase character");
}
if(uSafe){
   System.out.println("Your password has a least 1 lowercase character");
}
```

and i would scratch:

```
boolean safe = false;
boolean unsafe = true;

boolean hasLowercase = !a.equals(a.toUpperCase());
boolean hasUppercase = !a.equals(a.toLowerCase());
```

can't guarantee that is the best way but it should work.

Comment: A second one: standard naming conventions.

Comment: changed just for you JB